# userManagerAddToRole(User,Role) : System.InvalidOperationException:RoleDoes"Random Role Id string" not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework and ASP.NET MVC. In my project, I am trying to assign a role to a user. when I am trying to assign a role to the user, this error gets generated. Even though I tried to see in debugger, I get the Role Id and user id perfectly which I am expecting but when those `id` are passed to `userManager.AddToRole(User,Role)` it says role does not exist.

Here is my seed method where I am creating role. Those roles are getting created in `AspNetRoles` table.

```cs
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<VacationProjectV2.Models.ApplicationDbContext>
{
    private RoleManagement roleManager;
    private ApplicationDbContext dbContext;
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
        roleManager = new RoleManagement(dbContext);
    }

    protected override void Seed(VacationProjectV2.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.C:\Users\brahm\source\repos\VacationProjectV2\VacationProjectV2\App_Start\
        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data.
        roleManager.CreateRole("Admin")   //.ToString().ToUpper();
        roleManager.CreateRole("ProjectManager")  //.ToString().ToUpper();
        roleManager.CreateRole("Developer") //.ToString().ToUpper();
    }
}
```

Here is my AdminController where I am trying to assign it.

```cs
public class AdminsController : Controller
{
    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
    RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;

    public AdminsController()
    {
        roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(db));
        userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));
    }
    // GET: Admins

    public ActionResult AssignRole()
    {
        ViewBag.Users = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "UserName");
        ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(db.Roles, "Id", "Name");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AssignRole(string Users,String Roles)
    {
        userManager.AddToRole(Users, Roles);
        ViewBag.Users = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "UserName");
        ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(db.Roles, "Id", "Name");
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And here the `View` code

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AssignRoles";
}

<h2>AssignRoles</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownList("Users", "Select User");
    @Html.DropDownList("Roles","Select Role")
    <input type="Submit" value="Add Role"/>
}
```

So I wanted to see `UserId` and `RoleId` in `AspNetUserRoles` table. I don't know where I am making mistake. I tried to create roles in seed method using `.Tostrong().ToUpper()` by seeing another post with the same issue but it didn't work for me. Please let me know where I am making a mistake.

Comment: are you sure you can use simple string with "userManager.AddToRole(Users, Roles);" ?

Comment: I am not sure about that. I havent learn AddToRoleAsync method yet. So I cannot add string directly in AddToRole Method?

Comment: you shouls log what is users and roles from your post.  Pay attention, AddToRole and AddToRoleAsync are not the same.  What are you using?

Comment: I am using AddToRole. And thanks a lot I found My mistake I double-checked the method and AddToRole require Sting of `Role Name` Not The string of the `Role Id`. Now It Is working Perfectly fine Thanks @hugo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry Guys It was my bad I did not check the method required parameters correctly. The mistake was `userManager.AddToRole()`. Requires the `roleName` not the `roleId` as a parameter.

```
 public ActionResult AssignRoles()
        {
            ViewBag.Users = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "UserName");
            ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(db.Roles, "Name", "Name"); // Here I was Passing the Id insted Of Role Name.
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AssignRoles(string Users,string Roles)
        {
            usersManager.AddToRole(Users, Roles);
            ViewBag.Users = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "UserName");
            ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(db.Roles, "Name", "Name");
            return View();
        }
```